# Raise exception while parsing JSON with the wrong schema on the Optional field

Tags: scala, json4s

During JSON parsing, I want to catch an exception for optional sequential files which schema differed from my case class.
Let me elaborate

I have the following case class:

```
case class SimpleFeature(
  column: String,
  valueType: String,
  nullValue: String,
  func: Option[String])

case class TaskConfig(
  taskInfo: TaskInfo,
  inputType: String,
  training: Table,
  testing: Table,
  eval: Table,
  splitStrategy: SplitStrategy,
  label: Label,
  simpleFeatures: Option[List[SimpleFeature]],
  model: Model,
  evaluation: Evaluation,
  output: Output)
```

And this is part of JSON file I want to point attention to:

```
"simpleFeatures": [
  {
    "column": "pcat_id",
    "value": "categorical",
    "nullValue": "DUMMY"
  },
  {
    "column": "brand_code",
    "valueType": "categorical",
    "nullValue": "DUMMY"
  }
]
```

As you can see the first element has an error in the schema and while parsing, I want to raise an error. At the same time, I want to keep optional behavior in case there is no object to parse.

One idea that I've been researching for a while - to create the custom serializer and manually check fields, but not sure I'm on the right track

```
object JSONSerializer extends CustomKeySerializer[SimpleFeatures](format => {
  case jsonObj: JObject => {
    case Some(simplFeatures (jsonObj \ "simpleFeatures")) => {
    // Extraction logic goes here
    }
  }
})
```

I might be not quite proficient in Scala and json4s so any advice is appreciated.

```
json4s version
3.2.10

scala version
2.11.12

jdk version
1.8.0
```

Comment: I thought of using them but I'm afraid that could be more difficult due to the backward compatibility. Though I'll have a look.

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to extend `CustomSerializer` class since `CustomKeySerializer` it is used to implement custom logic for JSON keys:

```scala
import org.json4s.{CustomSerializer, MappingException}
import org.json4s.JsonAST._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

case class SimpleFeature(column: String,
                          valueType: String,
                          nullValue: String,
                          func: Option[String])

case class TaskConfig(simpleFeatures: Option[Seq[SimpleFeature]])

object Main extends App {

implicit val formats = new DefaultFormats {
    override val strictOptionParsing: Boolean = true
  } + new SimpleFeatureSerializer()

  class SimpleFeatureSerializer extends CustomSerializer[SimpleFeature](_ => ( {
    case jsonObj: JObject =>
      val requiredKeys = Set[String]("column", "valueType", "nullValue")

      val diff = requiredKeys.diff(jsonObj.values.keySet)
      if (diff.nonEmpty)
        throw new MappingException(s"Fields [${requiredKeys.mkString(",")}] are mandatory. Missing fields: [${diff.mkString(",")}]")

      val column = (jsonObj \ "column").extract[String]
      val valueType = (jsonObj \ "valueType").extract[String]
      val nullValue = (jsonObj \ "nullValue").extract[String]
      val func = (jsonObj \ "func").extract[Option[String]]

      SimpleFeature(column, valueType, nullValue, func)
  }, {
    case sf: SimpleFeature =>
      ("column" -> sf.column) ~
        ("valueType" -> sf.valueType) ~
        ("nullValue" -> sf.nullValue) ~
        ("func" -> sf.func)
  }
  ))

  // case 1: Test single feature
  val singleFeature  = """
          {
              "column": "pcat_id",
              "valueType": "categorical",
              "nullValue": "DUMMY"
          }
      """
  val singleFeatureValid = parse(singleFeature).extract[SimpleFeature]
  println(singleFeatureValid)
  //  SimpleFeature(pcat_id,categorical,DUMMY,None)

  // case 2: Test task config
  val taskConfig  = """{
      "simpleFeatures": [
        {
          "column": "pcat_id",
          "valueType": "categorical",
          "nullValue": "DUMMY"
        },
        {
          "column": "brand_code",
          "valueType": "categorical",
          "nullValue": "DUMMY"
        }]
  }"""

  val taskConfigValid = parse(taskConfig).extract[TaskConfig]
  println(taskConfigValid)
  //  TaskConfig(List(SimpleFeature(pcat_id,categorical,DUMMY,None), SimpleFeature(brand_code,categorical,DUMMY,None)))

  // case 3: Invalid json
  val invalidSingleFeature  = """
          {
              "column": "pcat_id",
              "value": "categorical",
              "nullValue": "DUMMY"
          }
      """
  val singleFeatureInvalid = parse(invalidSingleFeature).extract[SimpleFeature]
  // throws MappingException
}
```

*Analysis*: the main question here is how to gain access to the keys of `jsonObj` in order to check whether there is an invalid or missing key, one way to achieve that is through `jsonObj.values.keySet`. For the implementation, first we assign the mandatory fields to the `requiredKeys` variable, then we compare the `requiredKeys` with the ones that are currently present with `requiredKeys.diff(jsonObj.values.keySet)`. If the difference is not empty that means there is a missing mandatory field, in this case we throw an exception including the necessary information.

*Note1:* we should not forget to add the new serializer to the available formats.

*Note2:* we throw an instance of MappingException, which is already used by json4s internally when parsing JSON string.

**UPDATE**

In order to force validation of Option fields you need to set `strictOptionParsing` option to true by overriding the corresponding method:

```scala
implicit val formats = new DefaultFormats {
    override val strictOptionParsing: Boolean = true
  } + new SimpleFeatureSerializer()
```

**Resources**

https://nmatpt.com/blog/2017/01/29/json4s-custom-serializer/

https://danielasfregola.com/2015/08/17/spray-how-to-deserialize-entities-with-json4s/

https://www.programcreek.com/scala/org.json4s.CustomSerializer

Comment: hi @Daniel, could you try this out?

Comment: hi, @Alexandros. Thanks for sharing, I appreciate your help. Seem I need to explore CustomSerializer deeply
Currently, I'm solving two problems (https://scastie.scala-lang.org/efiyEZ9ATIWqqYPg8UgtGw):
1. I expanded the TaskConfig case class with objects other than SimpleFeatures. Seems that I need to add an extra step in  SimpleFeatureSerializer to check the field name. Trying to figure out the proper way of handling this. 
2. Also, please take a look at test case #4. If you set the SimpleFeature field to Optional the exception will not raise. That was the initial problem I tried to solve

Comment: No problem @Daniel my pleasure if it is possible to help. I will try to take a look later today

Comment: @Daniel the problem was that in your JSON. TaskInfo instance is named taskInfo while the member of your class classConfig :) just fix that and it should work

Comment: Thanks, I need to be more attentive to details. Still, event after correcting, the issue remains. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/AYXZLVtqS1GuQafbNEgjuw
Take a look at the last test case please. The expected behavior is to throw an exception, but the json file was parsed with the following results  `TaskConfig(TaskInfo(v2v_forever_set_dedup_eval,ranking),None)`

Comment: yes indeed and that is because of Option combined with Seq, if you remove it the exception occurs. Do you really need option here? Wouldn't an empty Seq work for you? If you really need it, I believe that you may need write a custom serializer for TaskConfig class eg TaskConfigSerializer

Comment: Yeah, that the point of the initial question. Sometimes you can make a mistake in a single SimpleFeature element and that will cause improper behavior. I thought about customer serializer for TaskConfig but the initial config has around 40 fields.

Comment: @Daniel I will take a look at it, if there is no alternative I will update the answer with a new serializer for the TaskConfig class

Comment: @Daniel as discussed [here](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/356) one way to fix this is by overriding the method which controls Option fields behaviour (false by default). I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `play.api.libs.json`

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.7.2",
"net.liftweb" % "lift-json_2.11" % "2.6.2"
```

You just need to define case class and formatters.

Example:

```
case class Example(a: String, b: String)

implicit val formats: DefaultFormats.type = DefaultFormats
implicit val instancesFormat= Json.format[Example]
```

and then just do :

```
Json.parse(jsonData).asOpt[Example]
```

In case the above gives some errors: Try adding   `"net.liftweb" % "lift-json_2.11" % "2.6.2"` too in your dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But firstly I'd love to stay with the json4s as it widely used in the project.